# Prevent event from parent element to child element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have bound event as below:

```
    $(document).delegate('.budget', 'click', function(e){
        if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
           $(this).removeClass('collapsed');
           $(this).addClass('expanded');
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
           $(this).removeClass('expanded');
           $(this).addClass('collapsed');
        }
    });
```

Basically this toggles between expand and collapse.

I have another event bound as below:

```
    $('[id^="tree"]').delegate('.collapsed', 'click', function(e){
        var elementId = $(this).attr('id');
        hideChildElement(elementId);
    });
```

The elements bound by the second event binding are parents of elements binded by first event binding.
What happens is that on clicking on the element from the first binding event method also triggers the event bound by second event binding.
I want to prevent any events from binding from second event binding to 1st event binding method.

If element A is bound to click event from first event binding and B is bound to second event binding (A is inside B or A is child of B), I dont want any event of B to propagate to A. 
Note I tried `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` but did not worked

Comment: As a side note, you could simplify the toggling with `$(this).toggleClass("expanded collapsed")`.

Comment: sonam sorry i can't get the logic (A in B, B in A). However `:not` selector is what you are looking for

Comment: A is child of B, for eg: <div id="parent"><span id="child"></span></div>

Comment: @Zoltan: You are not using event delegation.

Comment: @FelixKling even with delegation - http://jsfiddle.net/PVHme/1/

Comment: @Zoltan: It still does not replicate the situation. The event handler for the parent elements has to be bound to an element closer to them, not to the root. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/PVHme/2/. Of course if the OP just changes this and binds both handlers to `document`, `stopImmediatePropagation` works.

Comment: @Felix So let's bind the child event handler to container (not root) as well - http://jsfiddle.net/PVHme/3/

Comment: @Zoltan: Yes, as long as the event handlers are bound to the same element it works fine. However it might not be a viable solution for the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to prevent the event handler bound to `[id^="tree"]` to be triggered if a `.budged` element was clicked. In that case you can test where the click event originated from:

```
$('[id^="tree"]').delegate('.collapsed', 'click', function(e){
    if($(e.target).closest('.budget').length === 0) {
        // not from inside budget element
        var elementId = $(this).attr('id');
        hideChildElement(elementId);
    }
});
```

Alternatively, if you bind both event handlers to the same element, i.e. both to `document` or `[id^="tree"]` or any element in between, `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` will work just fine.

If this is not what you want, please clarify your question, it is not easy to understand.

Comment: yes i want to prevent event being propagated to the first event binding

Comment: Then this should work. If not you have to indeed provide more information, especially your markup.

Comment: thank you soooo much, spent my whole day trying to solve this. you made my day